# iOS: Stretching ImageView Above My TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have added a `UIImageView` on top of my `tableView` in storyboard & it works perfectly fine, except that when you scroll down, the `imageView` doesn't stick to the `navigationBar` and instead only sticks on to the `tableView` (revealing the view's background above it).

How would I get it to stick to both the `tableView` and the `navigationBar`, and just have the `imageView` stretch/zoom as the user pulls the `tableView` down?

This is how it's set up in storyboard:
[image]

And this is how I assign an image to it in my `ViewDidLoad:`

```
childHeaderView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:headerImage];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried setting constraints on it using autoLayout but it doesn't seem to let me (they're grayed out, even though I've enabled it for that `ViewController`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that what you did in storyboard is adding the `UIImageView` as a header to your `UITableView`.

The proper way to do this is to add the `UIImageView` at the same level as the `UITableView`, which mean embed these two views inside a `UIView`.

Having a `UIView` as a root view for a view controller is unfortunately impossible for a `UITableViewController`, and I fear that this is your case. So you may want to replace your `UITableViewController` subclass by a `UIViewController` subclass.

**EDIT**: You'll want to set a fixed height constraint on your `UIImageView`, and add a vertical space constraint with a 0pt value between your `UIImageView` and `UITableView`.
Most of these can be achieved by moving view in IB.

[image: Example of view positioning]

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. Fortunately I am using a UIViewController but just deleted the UIView. So If I Add the a UIView, and set the imageView and tableView at the same level, what methods or properties can help me stretch the imageView so that it is always touching the navBar and the tableView, no matter how far the user scrolls, and once they let go it'll snap back to it's original height.